# 'TypeError: integer argument expected, got float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm doing a game in python and I have one error

> integer argument expected, got float

, and I'm not understanding why. The line that give me error is:

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (128, 128, 128), 
    (self.location[0]-1, self.location[1]-1), self.size+1)
```

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.level = 1
        self.feed = 0
        self.size = 2
        self.speed = 6
        self.location = (SCREEN_SIZE[0]/2, SCREEN_SIZE[1]/2)
        self.destination = self.location
        self.stopDis = 5    #Stopping distance

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (128, 128, 128),
            (self.location[0]-1, self.location[1]-1), self.size+1)  #Error here
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, self.location, self.size)   #Draw circle
```

Comment: This problem does not occur on Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd parameter to [`pygame.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) has to be a integral coordinate (tuple `(x, y)`), but the result of a division (`/`) is a floationg point value.

Use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to cast [`self.location`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) from floating point values to integral values:

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (128, 128, 128), 
    (int(self.location[0]-1), int(self.location[1]-1)), self.size+1)
```

Or do a integral division (`//`) instead of the floating point division (`/`), when you calculate `self.location`:

```py
self.location = (SCREEN_SIZE[0] // 2, SCREEN_SIZE[1] // 2)
```

See also [Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).